# stripos returns false when special characters is used

Tags: php, strpos, string-search

I am using the [stripos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to check if a string is located inside another string, ignoring any cases.

Here is the problem:

```
stripos("ø", "Ø")
```

returns false. While

```
stripos("Ø", "Ø")
```

returns true.

As you might see, it looks like the function does *NOT* do a case-*insensitive* search in this case.

The function has the same problems with characters like Ææ and Åå. These are Danish characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`mb_stripos()`](http://php.net/mb_stripos) instead. It's character set aware and will handle multi-byte character sets. stripos() is a holdover from the good old days when there was only ASCII and all chars were only 1 byte.

Comment: Why oh why is this function not stated as a related function to stripos... Then I would have been able to find out myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can suggest it to the PHP documentation maintainers. Those doc pages aren't frozen for all eternity.

Answer (score 3):

You need [mb_stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php).

Comment: As much as I would like to accept both yours and Marc B's answer, I selected his since an explanation accompanied his answer.

Answer (score 1):

[mb_stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php) will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

As the other solutions say, try first with mb_stripos(). But if using this function doesn't help, **check the encoding of your php file. Convert it to UTF-8 and save it.** That did the trick for me after hours of research.