# How to make Stripos("UTF-8") in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, stripos

There is situation like this:

```
<?php
    $string="Tu gdzieś jest ten ŁAŻĄCY po lesie troll";
    //translatePL2EN($string)=="Somewhere here is the troll, who USUALLY WALKS through the forest."
    $result = stripos($string,'łażący');
    $result2 = mb_stripos($string,'łażący');
?>
```

I wanted to find case insensitive version of `ŁAŻĄCY` - `łażący` using `stripos();` or `mb_stripos();`

it should return int(20), but it returns false.

How to fix that?

[stripos returns false when special characters is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487917/stripos-returns-false-when-special-characters-is-used) this still not fix the problem.

Even this

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL', 'pl', 'Polish_Poland.28592');
$result = mb_stripos("ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ",'ęóąśłżźćń');
```

returns false...

Comment: I'd just like to point out... using an HTML `meta charset` tag in no way affects your PHP code. At all.

Comment: And, anyway, valid syntax is `<meta charset="utf-8">`, not `<meta charset=\"utf-8\">`.