# Checking if string contain values from an Array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 7.1.12 and I trying to check if values from an array are present in a string to do that I'm doing this:

```
public function checkWords($word) {
    $list = array('extinção','desativação','obrigatório');

    foreach($list as $l) {
        if (stripos($word, $l) !== false) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

and them I call the function

```
echo($this->checkWords('Físicaem desativação/extinção voluntária:23000.010237/2012-46''); //returns false
```

Now comes the weird part, if I go to the function and replace $l with let's say: 'hello'.

```
public function checkWords($word) {
        $list = array('extinção','desativação','obrigatório');

        foreach($list as $l) {
            if (stripos($word, 'extinção') !== false) {
                return true;
            } 
        }

    }
```

the function call will return true

```
echo($this->checkWords('Físicaem desativação/extinção voluntária:23000.010237/2012-46''); //returns true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't replicate your first example returning false: https://eval.in/928464

Comment: I think that this may be a charset problem, going to update the question with real data. Anyway here is the function with real data: https://eval.in/928469

Comment: Certainly looks like it: https://eval.in/928476

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried to utf8_encode() both of them but it did not work.

Comment: @André executing your eval in PHP 7.1.7 returns true.

Comment: Also here returns true: https://repl.it/@rvalenciano/PlasticModernCoral

Comment: `setlocale(LC_COLLATE, <portuguese locales>)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to deal with multi-byte characters at that time simple string function will not work. You have to use mb functions for it. There is list of mb functions which work with multi-byte characters, Check entire list here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Now for find position you can use `mb_stripos` function. Try below code:

```
function checkWords($word) {
    $list = array('extinção','desativação','obrigatório');
    foreach($list as $l) {
        if (mb_stripos($word, $l) !== false) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(checkWords('Físicaem desativação/extinção voluntária:23000.010237/2012-46')); // return true
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump(checkWords('Físicaema dessativação/extsinção voluntária:23000.010237/2012-46')); //return false
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/OMZjA)

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has a bounty, cannot flag it as duplicate, but the issue is with the function used in your case:

```
stripos($word, 'extinção')
```

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487917/stripos-returns-false-when-special-characters-is-used) is stated, stripos doesn't handle special characters very well and produces this non deterministic results. Use [mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the string encoding.

1) Check if using `mb_stripos` works. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php

2) if (1) fails you may be serving the file with the wrong encoding. Check if your file charset matches your html charset meta header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```